# add values from array of objects MONGODB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I want to get the total sum of an order. After the `$group` i am getting an array of objects that have the orderLineTotal fields. How to I sum up those? Is there a way to do it better?

```
db.orders.aggregate( [ 
    { $match : {orderNo : "1"} },
    { $unwind : "$orderLine"},
    { $group : { 
            _id : "$orderLine" ,
            orderLineTotal : {$sum: { $multiply: [ "$orderLine.price", "$orderLine.amount" ] }}
        }
    },
] )

// output

[
  {
    "_id": {
      "isbn": "0002",
      "price": {
        "$numberDecimal": "600"
      },
      "amount": 2
    },
    "orderLineTotal": {
      "$numberDecimal": "1200" // sum this
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "isbn": "0001",
      "price": {
        "$numberDecimal": "642.4"
      },
      "amount": 2
    },
    "orderLineTotal": {
      "$numberDecimal": "1284.8" // with this
    }
  }
]

// desired output

{
 total : 2484.8
}
```

Comment: i am not sure what is your expectation, use `_id : null,` in the group stage.

Comment: yes, this worked out but I dont understand why

Comment: you have to understand the [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage, pass the field name in `_id` that you want to group by, but if you want to group all documents in a single document then use null, or any empty string.